# How to assign the whole value of one char array into another array of one position into hex format in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, hex

I want to store the hexadecimal value format like "0x12" into the array of one position from another array. I am able to change into the hexadecimal string like "0x12" but not able to assign the whole value into the one position of array.
Can I know, where I am doing wrong?

```
    char b[5];
    int a= 20;
    char hex[5];
    sprintf(hex,"0x%d",a);
    printf("hex: %s\n",hex);
    b[0]=hex;
    printf("b[0]: %s\n",b);
```

Expected result:

```
hex: 0x20,
b[0]: 0x20
```

Actual result:

```
hex: 0x20,
b[0]:
```

Comment: `b[0]` is a `char`; it cannot hold a character array

Comment: Please read up on what in C a `char` means. Also helpful might be the notion of 0-terminated character sequences, which are referenced by `char*`, i.e. pointers to `char`. That is what is used in C to store "strings", which as such do not exist in C.

Comment: If you assign the integer value 20 to a suitable variable `x`, then `x!=0x20` will be true. You are aware of that, aren't you?

Comment: Yeah, it can't hold the character array. I am storing the a[0]=0x20 directly, this is possible. But how can I can store the "0x20" into the array of one position? Is there any way to do that? @MarkBenningfield

Comment: If you want to copy a character array into a single position in an array, then that array has to be an array of allocated `char*` or an array of `char[]`.

Comment: @Yunnosch .. I have tried with pointer to array also. My goal is, I am taking the character or integer like "20" and concatenate with "0x" which will be "0x20" and store into the one position of array. I can concatenate with sprintf or strcat function but the value should be in "0x20" format to store in b[0] = 0x20, b[1] =0x20 like this.

Comment: I think you want: `b[0] = strtol(hex+2, NULL, 16); printf("b[0]: %02X\n", b[0]);`.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving aside the fact that the hexadecimal equivalent of decimal 20 is 0x14, not 0x20, if you want to store the C-string "0x20" in a single position in an array, then that array has to be an array of allocated `char*`, or an array of `char[]`, like so:

**Pointers:**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char **b;
  int i;
  int a = 20;

  b = calloc(5, sizeof *b);
  if (b == NULL) {
    printf("Malloc failed");
    return 1;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    b[i] = malloc(sizeof b[0]);
    if (b[i] == NULL) {
      printf("malloc failed - fatal error");
      // here should be code to free the values that WERE allocated.
      return 1;
    }
  }
  sprintf(b[0], "0x%d", a);
  printf("hex: %s\n", b[0]);
  printf("b[0]: %s\n", b[0]);
  a = 30;
  sprintf(b[1], "0x%d", a);
  printf("hex: %s\n", b[1]);
  printf("b[1]: %s\n", b[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

**Character arrays:**

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char hex1[5];
    char hex2[5];
    char hex3[5];
    char hex4[5];
    char hex5[5];
    char b[5][5] = { hex1, hex2, hex3, hex4, hex5 };
    int a= 20;

    sprintf(b[0],"0x%d",a);
    printf("hex: %s\n",b[0]);
    printf("b[0]: %s\n",b[0]);
    a = 30;
    sprintf(b[1], "0x%d", a);
    printf("hex: %s\n", b[1]);
    printf("b[1] %s\n", b[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

Or any reasonable combination of the two.